# Gstreamer unable to link API's , Linker error

Tags: ubuntu, c, links, mpeg, gstreamer

I was trying to read the PAT table information , Color Balance interface etc  using gstreamer in ubuntu . but the the definitions of the API's used by gstreamer to achieve these are not available  .The linker always gives an error saying "UNDEFINED REFERENCE to" .

Eg API i tried :

```
gst_color_balance_list_channels,`gst_color_balance_get_value,`,gst_color_balance_get_type
,gst_message_parse_mpegts_section
```

command im using to compile

```
gcc dislpay.c -o exe_display `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

What am i missing ? how to link the  API's to their definitions .

Answer (score 0):

need to give the library name in the command line .As the definitions  of many API's are not available in gstreamer-1.0 itself ,  Telling the GCC to link with these libraries  during linking time will help to solve this problem .

The command i used

```
gcc dislpay.c -o exe_dispaly `pkg-config --cflags --libs  gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 gstreamer-0.10 `
```